# PHP simple html dom, trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I get the next notice when firing a specific function:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

My function:

```
private function rate($form)
{
    $score = 0;

    $count = $form->find('input')->length;
    $score += ($count >= 2 && $count <= 5) ? INPUT_COUNT_RATE : 0;

    $count = $form->find('textarea')->length;
    $score += $count == 1 ? TEXTAREA_COUNT_RATE : 0;

    return $score;
}
```

The problematic lines are the lines with the `find` function.

A `var_dump` of `$form` returns:

```
object(simple_html_dom_node)[1062]...
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`->find()` returns either an array of matched nodes, or null. You can't call `->length` on find results, because the results are not an object. Try

```
$nodes = $form->find(...);
$count = count($nodes);
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for helping.